# How can I pass an array to @Query annotation in Spring with MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

So im trying to make a custom query in Spring Boot with MongoDB. I need to pass an array in the $or operator.

Example query in MongoDB:

```
{title: {'$regex':'Ab','$options':'i'}, $or: [{ genre: 'Romance'}, {genre: 'Music'}], release_date: { $gte: "2000", $lte: "2020"}}
```

The Mongo Repository in Spring Boot

```
@Query("{title: { '$regex':?0,'$options':'i' }, $or: ?1, release_date: { $gte: ?2, $lte: ?3 }}")
List<Movie> findAllByFilters(String title, String[] genres, String min_date, String max_date);
```

This code is throwing an error:

```
Query failed with error code 2 with name 'BadValue' and error message '$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects'
```

Any solution to this?

I tried with Arrays, Lists, Collections and nothing in working.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you're passing to the `$or`.

You're trying to get a query like this `[{ genre: 'Romance'}, {genre: 'Music'}]`, but you're only sending it ["Romance", "Music"].  I think that you want to use a `$in` operator instead of your `$or`.

Your query would look something like this:

```
@Query("{title: { '$regex':?0,'$options':'i' }, {genre: {$in: ?1}}, release_date: { $gte: ?2, $lte: ?3 }}")
```

Comment: The `$or` shouldn't be necessary with `$in` in this case, since there's only one element inside the `$or`: `@Query("{title: { '$regex':?0,'$options':'i' }, genre: {$in: ?1}, release_date: { $gte: ?2, $lte: ?3 }}")`.

Comment: @M.Justin 100% correct, updated the answer